# Customizable Notifications UI

Tags: user-interface, design-patterns

I am trying to implement customizable notifications. The notification itself consists of text and some placeholders for system-generated data:

[alt text http://arsds.com/sample.png](http://arsds.com/sample.png) (http://www.evernote.com/pub/lkurts/public#Note/aab1e6eb-1eaf-4b9d-8cef-6bd499be0bb9)

As you can see the placeholder is in square brackets: [User Name].  For each notification, a number of allowed placeholders exists.

I am trying to figure out the UI way of presenting these placeholders to the user. Here is one example from the "Quickbase' application:

[alt text http://arsds.com/QB.png](http://arsds.com/QB.png) (http://www.evernote.com/pub/lkurts/public#Note/fc0b6f66-f792-406c-9751-b88250d3ef9c)

Are there any established ways of doing this? UI Design Patterns? Maybe some samples of how other applications are dealing with this?

Comment: Hope they can be seen now, don't know what happened.

Comment: Please try URL in parens - looks like Evernote does not allow sharing direct image links. Sorry about the confusion :-(

Answer (score 1):

Here's a screenshot from a web-based application we use at my company. The screenshot is the template used for mail sent to job applicants. As you can see it's very similar to your Quickbase screenshot.

[Message template http://img41.imageshack.us/img41/7295/picture2kss.png](http://img41.imageshack.us/img41/7295/picture2kss.png)